# SQL query for showing total votes per user in SO-like system

Tags: sql

Consider a simplified table schema of a StackOverflow-like system:

**Tables:**
*User* ( id, name )
*Question* ( id, user_id, question )
*Vote* ( id, question_id )

How would I write a SQL query that would

- List each user along with the total votes for all his questions, ordered by most votes?
- Given a user_id, return a single user record, along with his total votes?

User Name | Total Votes (desc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select User.id,
User.name,
count(vote.id) as Votes
from User 
left join Question
on User.id = Question.user_id
left join Vote
on Vote.question_id = Question.id
group by user.id, User.name
order by 3 desc
```

Comment: JBrooks- Bingo! This worked out of the box- thanks. Can you explain what the "else 1" part is doing? (Also, your other answer doesn't work- assuming it's a mistake- can you delete?)

Comment: @Yarin,  if there is a user that does not have a record in the Question table than vote.id will be null and you want to count this as zero votes. If he does have a record you want to count it as 1.

Comment: @JBrooks- changed 'sum' to 'count' - seems to work just as well. Any objection?

Answer (score 1):

For your first question:

```
SELECT u.name, COUNT(v.id) AS TotalVotes
    FROM User u
        LEFT JOIN Question q
            INNER JOIN Vote v
                ON q.id = v.question_id
            ON u.id = q.user_id
    GROUP BY u.name
    ORDER BY TotalVotes DESC
```

For your second question:

```
SELECT u.name, COUNT(v.id) AS TotalVotes
    FROM User u
        LEFT JOIN Question q
            INNER JOIN Vote v
                ON q.id = v.question_id
            ON u.id = q.user_id
    WHERE u.id = @GivenUserId
    GROUP BY u.name
```

Comment: the OP has the data requested to be ordered by TotalVotes

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer: Added the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: think you need a group by also.

Comment: @Joe- Not working for me- I'm getting an [ near "ON": syntax error ] using SQLite

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT user.name, question.question, count(vote.id) votes
    FROM user
    inner join question on user.id=question.user_id
    inner join vote on question.id=vote.question_id
    GROUP BY user.name, question.question
    ORDER BY votes
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the subselect just to sort the result.

Comment: @Angelo- this has two problems: 1- grouping by question, when only should be by user (i can fix that), 1- doesn't give me users with 0 votes- I need all users

Comment: @Yarin: I'd recommend Joes solution over mine.